# ReactJS hosting in a subfolder not working properly

Tags: reactjs, url, path, router, hostname

I'm trying to host my ReactJS project in a subfolder on my webhost.

I put my project (production) in a folder called "dashboard". So now I can access the website by http://hostname/dashboard.

However, it gives me the following error as it still tries to grab styles.css and bundle.js from the main folder.

[image]

What can I do to fix it?

```
function MainContent() {
  return (
    <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need something like a base_url. Check the recommended way in this blog article: https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but if you are using AWS you have to assign an extra server for the route which increases cost by lot more. Couldn't find any optimal solution after looking everywhere.